# How can I "patch" a JPA entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jpa

Let's pretend a RESTful service receives a `PATCH` request to update one or more fields of an entity that might have tens of fields.

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

 // many other fields
}
```

One dirty way to *patch* the corresponding entity is to write something like this:

```
SomeEntity patch = deserialize(json);
SomeEntity existing = findById(patch.getId());
if (existing != null) 
{
 if (patch.getField1() != null) 
 {
   existing.setField1(patch.getField1());
 }
 if (patch.getField2() != null) 
 {
   existing.setField2(patch.getField2());
 }
 if (patch.getField3() != null) 
 {
   existing.setField3(patch.getField3());
 }
}
```

But this is insane! And if I want to patch 1 to many & other associations of the entity the insanity could even become hazardous!

Is there a sane an elegant way to achieve this task?

Comment: What if you want to set `null` to a field?

Comment: What has "JPA" got to do with this? The same applies to ANY Java object with fields!

Answer (score 0):

Modify the getter's of SomeEntity and apply check, if any value is blank or null just return the corresponding entity object value.

```
class SomeEntity {
    transient SomeEntity existing;
    private String name;
    public String getName(){
        if((name!=null&&name.length()>0)||existing==null){
            return name;
        }
        return existing.getName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send an array containing the name of the fields you are going to patch. Then, in the server side, by reflection or any field mapping, set each field to the entity. I have already implemented that and it works, thought my best advice is this:

Don't publish an endpoint to perform a "generic" PATCH (modification), but one that performs a specific operation. For instance, if you want to modify an employee's address, publish an endpoint like:

```
PUT /employees/3/move
```

that expects a JSON with the new address `{"address" : "new address"}`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel by writing the logic yourself, why don't you use a mapping library like Dozer? You want to use the 'map-null' mapping property: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/exclude.html

EDIT I am not sure whether or not it would be possible to map a class onto itself. You could use an intermediary DTO, though.